# Is avalanche much better than earthquake?

Tags: diablo-iii

Damage is the same 4400 %

Cooldown of avalanche is much better.

Also you can cast avalanche far, but not earthquake.

Yet I somehow feel that earthquake hurt enemies more. My barb has 250k dps and  earthquake sort of kill a 40 million HP monster.

Not avalanche.

Am I missing something?

I am thinking avalanche 4400% rune and earthquake molten furry, 4500%

They both have roughly the same damage yet vastly different cooldown. Also earthquake molen furry seems to hit harder.

Answer (score 2):

Earthquake is a move that you use when enemies are around you. Avalanche is for barbs that do more ranged damage like weapon throw. I usually use leap + earthquake to get right in the middle of the action. The moves are similar, but not the same.

Runes on earthquake will sometimes do + damage over time

Avalanche base skill: Cause a massive avalanche of rocks to fall on an area dealing 1600% weapon damage to all enemies caught in its path.

Earthquake base skill: Shake the ground violently, dealing 2600% weapon damage as Fire over 8 seconds to all enemies within 18 yards.

So you can see that earthquake deals more base damage over time as long as enemies are standing in it.

Comment: Make sense. But why earthquake has more damage even though both have 4400 % weapon damage?

Comment: @JimThio I edited my post with more information for you.

Comment: One of the rune, which I used, have similar damage. Around 4500%

Comment: any other answer? I already mentioned that both uses runes around 4500%

Comment: earthquake is affected by bul kathos passive skill. Avalanche is not. Also earth quake kills more enemies.